# How do you know whether to automate testing or use manual?

Tags: c#, winforms, automated-tests

I've made a login screen and menu for a Doctors management system. User logs in and is sent to main menu, depending on role type they have different controls on each sub menu.

It all works well and now its time to test.

I've never done automated testing - unit, integration or end to end.

As I understand, it's best to seperate business logic from presentation logic and only unit test the business logic?

With that in mind button visibility and messageboxes are presenation logic, right? and are best suited to a manual test plan in which I'll validate the functionality? Is that right?

I'm sure I should unit test if login is succeccful? however, isn't the method dependent on a database? so is that then integration testing?

here's my code

**Login form**

```
 private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        //Try and open a connection with database and run the code
        try
        {

            //Create new instance of sql connection, pass in the connection string for BayOneSurgerySystem.mdf to connect to database.
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\davie\Documents\UniWork\Software Engineering\BayOneSurgerySystem1.0\Database\BayOneSystem.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

            //Create new instance of SQlCommand and pass in a query to be called to retrieve table data for username and passwords aswell as the connection object.
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = @username and Password = @password", conn);
            //This passes user input into @username and @password
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtBoxUsername.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtBoxPassword.Text);

            //Open connection with database
            conn.Open();

            //Create new instance of dataSet to hold the data retrieved from sql query
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            //Create new instance of DataAdpater to retrieve the data pass in Sql command
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            //using DataAdapter fill in dataSet wiht data if user input and stored data matches
            da.Fill(ds);

            //Close the connection now data table is filled with username and password
            conn.Close();

            //declare bool, true if there is a match with database and user input
            bool loginSuccess = (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1);


            //if login success is true then open menu
            if (loginSuccess)
            {
                /*Change state of enum RoleTypes based on result from dataSet Role_ID column.
                 In UserRole table records are as follows: 
                 Role_ID 1 = PracticeManager
                 2 = Doctor
                 3 = Receptionist*/

                //Print role_ID to console to check that is been set.
                Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Role_ID"]);

                try
                {
                    //Condition for the switch statement is: check Role_ID from UserRoles table
                    switch (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Role_ID"])
                    {
                        //if the case is that Role_ID for the user logged in is 1 then run the function etc.
                        case 1:
                            {
                                Roles.Role = Roles.RoleType.practiceManager;
                                Console.WriteLine("Role type changed to " + Roles.Role);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            {
                                Roles.Role = Roles.RoleType.doctor;
                                Console.WriteLine("Role type changed to " + Roles.Role);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            {
                                Roles.Role = Roles.RoleType.receptionist;
                                Console.WriteLine("Role type changed to " + Roles.Role);
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;

                    }
                }//Switch condition cannot be reached then catch exception and print to console.
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }


                Console.WriteLine("Logged in.");
                FrmMenu menu = new FrmMenu();
                menu.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password.", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel);
                Console.WriteLine("Not logged in");
            }


        }

        //If connection cant be opened diplsay error message and catch exception and print to console
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry can't connect");
        }



    }

}
```

}

**Role class**

```
 public static class Roles
{
    /*The RoleType enum is declared here and changed in form login. RoleType is the condition for button visibility
    I.e if roletype is doctor, show doctor buttons*/
    public static RoleType Role;
    public enum RoleType
    {
        practiceManager,
        doctor,
        receptionist

    }


}
```

**Patient form**

```
//if this is clicked, display yesNo messagebox. If yes, logout.
    private void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            FrmLogin logout = new FrmLogin();
            logout.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    private void FrmPatients_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        /*Buttons are visible depending on access level. Permissions are as follows:
         * Practice Manager - Patient Records
           Doctor - Register Patient, Patient notes
           Receptionist - New Patient, Register Patient*/
        if (Roles.Role == Roles.RoleType.practiceManager)
        {
            this.btnNewPatient.Visible = false;
            this.btnNotes.Visible = false;
            this.btnSignIn.Visible = false;

        }

        else if (Roles.Role == Roles.RoleType.doctor)
        {
            this.btnNewPatient.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            this.btnNotes.Visible = false;
        }

    }

    //if this is clicked return to main menu
    private void pcBxBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FrmMenu menu = new FrmMenu();
        this.Close();
        menu.Show();
    }
}
```

}

**Test class**

```
 [TestClass]

     public class LoginTests
     {
       [TestMethod]
         public void Constuctor_NormalData_Login_Is_Successful()
         {

            //Arrange
            //Act
            //Assert
          }


        [TestMethod]
        public void Constructor_RoleTypeEnum_RoleType_Changes()
        {
           //Arrange
           //Act
           //Assert

         }


       }
```

Any advice on what you would use automated testing for?

I've got a manual table with 21 tests validating all messageboxes, button click events and button visibility.

For an A I really need some automated testing. As you can see I've got template for testing role type enum and login succesful, those are the only 2 obvious methods to test that I can see.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you case, avoid unit testing and go for end to end testing.

---

Your question is very vague - something we try to avoid here at Stack overflow, beceause it makes it hard to answer. At best answers will be vague. At worst the question will be voted for closing and the questioner (i.e. you) will lose energy.

With that said, I go for a vague answer.

Looking at your `btnLogin_Click` method I see that you have not separated business logic from the user interface. Said method knows how to connect to a database and how to query it natively and it knows about the user interface to update it and also knows how to log to a console. It probably knows more but this enough for me to advice you against unit testing.
Unit testing is, simply put, a way to verify the cogs in your machine look and behave like you want.
Your machine has alla cogs and levers and sprints and spindles mixed together. I am not saying your code is bad; but if you want to *unit test* it you have a hard time ahead of you.

Instead go for *end to end testing*.
Visual studio has a way to [automate applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/using-ui-automation-for-automated-testing). (I don't know if you have to have a special license level as Microsoft "forgets" to describe this when the features of Visual studio are explained.
Then there is [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/).
Then there are more.
I don't recommend the ones above or any other but that has to be your choice. Dig around and test to find one you like. Many are F/OSS.

HTH
and happy hacking!

Comment: This is extemely helpful! Thats what I thought. **End-To-End Testing** is what I need, awsome. Trying to figure out how to use **Arrange, Act, Assert** whilst knowing that the login method is dependant on a database. You've got me on the right track though! I'm looking at **Coded UI test** as I have **Visual Studio Enterprise**. I'm wondering if my university does not have enterprise will that make it difficult to run my program in uni or see the test?